# Python: Line and bar graph with year on X axis?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to have the years on the X-axis, the volume represented by the bars and the value represented by the line. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'Year' : [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
                         'Volume' : [32, 35, 33, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 49, 47],
                         'Value' : [40, 41, 46, 44, 43, 42, 42, 45, 48, 52]})

data1[['Year', 'Volume']].plot(kind='bar', width = 0.5, color="navy")
data1['Value'].plot(secondary_y=True, color='orange')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass `X='Year'` into the plot commands.

```
data1[['Year', 'Volume']].plot(x='Year',kind='bar', width = 0.5, color="navy")
data1['Value'].plot(secondary_y=True, color='orange')
```

Output:

[image]