# Second axis in twinx is invisible

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

First, background: I'm pulling my data from Pandas. A more thorough MWE on my data is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75480295/8954291).

I'm trying to generate a graph that looks like this, but in Pandas:
[image]

I can get each of the axes on their own:

```py
tmp = df_totals.loc[("Grand","Total"),(slice(None),slice("Applied","Admitted"))].to_frame().unstack()
tmp.columns = ["Admitted","Applied"]
ax1 = tmp.plot.bar()
```

[image]

```py
tmp2 = df_totals.loc[("Grand","Total"),(slice(None),"\\%")].to_frame().unstack()
tmp2.columns = ["\\%"]
tmp2.plot.line()
```

[image]

Following [this guide](https://www.statology.org/pareto-chart-python/), I tried to build the plot from tmp2 as a `twinx`'d plot:

```py
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(tmp2, color='red', marker="D",ls="-")
```

[image]

And we can see that the right axis has the correct bounds, but there's no line. How do I get a line?

Other things I've tried:

- calling `reset_index()` on `tmp2` and then passing in `tmp2["Year"]` and `tmp2["\\%"]`
- Doing the above but passing just `"Year"` and `"\\%"` and `data=tmp2`

Based on the comments by Quang Hoang, I wrote the following, which works but feels really unpythonic:

```py
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(range(len(tmp2.index)), tmp2["\\%"], color='red', marker="D",ls="-")
```

Comment: `df.plot.bar()` plots data against range index `0...3`, the `2017...2020` are just text labels.

Comment: That indeed appears to be the case. Doing `ax2 = ax1.twinx().twiny()` plotted both visually, though the axis padding was smaller so the data points aren't aligned . I was under the impression that the two axes would work together because their frames share their index. Is there any way to merge their axes?

Comment: I'd do what you already wrote, i.e. plot line against range index, completely natural to me. Another way is to manually plot the bars against the years with native matplotlib `ax.bar`.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367498/python-line-and-bar-graph-with-year-on-x-axis/63367514#63367514)